# VS2010 Custom Tool / Add-in redistributable license

Tags: visual-studio-sdk, redistributable, customtool

I've built a custom tool that descends from the BaseCodeGeneratorWithSite class defined in one of the assemblies included in the VS2010 SDK. Does anyone know what the proper procedure is for redistributing this without requiring the end user to download the entire SDK?

I could include the required assemblies in the installer but I'm not sure if that's allowed under the SDK license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own implementation like [guys did here](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidEBCB57E35AB2C454BEBADE7446F4BE99D19E843D.aspx?s=idef%3afile) for PInvoke tool.

Comment: Looks good; guess I'll trust that the name "IVSSingleFileGenerator" isn't copyrighted.